# Bullets and numbering is not displayed in recipient mail by sending email through outlook 2007

Tags: email, outlook-2007

Compose an email with bullets/numbering info in Outlook 2007 and send. Then, observe that bullets/numbering is not displayed in the recipient email inbox of Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what HTML markup you use at the moment...

Anyway, by default Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup of message bodies. You may find supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)